# Can I export matrix to Excel from SAS University on PC under VMWare

Tags: excel, matrix, sas, vmware

I wish to write to Excel on my PC a "big" matrix of p rows and c columns, e.g.
3,000 rows and 20 columns.  But it's not easy, and I'm wondering if I can simplify it by using a fixed number for rows and columns instead of:

```
array mat               {&periods,&columns};
```

Right now, I'm on the free version of SAS called "SAS University Edition", which has only community help.

I would like to output it to Excel, but using VMWARE on a PC to get SAS Studio to run, you can't write directly to disk (although there is a myfolder).

I tried this, but got this error log:

```
 proc export data=WORK.CPAPMONTE1 
file= "/folders/myfolders/outfile1.xlsx"
DBMS=xlsx
;
run;
```

> ERROR: XLSX file can not be created -> /folders/myfolders//outfile1.xlsx. Make  sure the path name is correct and that you have
>    write permission.
>
> ERROR: Too many variables for the output file

I figure that the 2nd error is just due to the first error, which has a // instead of a /

> 2. I have defined a special folder for my data in SAS University Edition as: 
>      /folders/myfolders/CPAP1

but I haven't figured out how to point to there

Comment: Actually no, you can contact SAS Support for help. or SAS community specifically at communities.sas.com

Comment: SAS doesn't give help on its **free** version of SAS under VMWare.  But SAS community may be an idea, which I hadn't thought of.  Thanks.

Comment: SAS UE is essentially the same as working with SAS on a server, most of the issues you'll run into are along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write directly to disk, you need to set up a shared folder similar to myfolders and then you reference its as

```
/folders/myshortcuts/myname
```

The folder and shortcut must be exactly correct, and all need to be lower case as it's case sensitive. If you have myfolders set up, all you need to do is right click on the folder>Properties and you'll get the path to the folder. Use that in your export. A similar process can be used for the custom shared folder you set up.

SAS University Edition Help Center/FAQ

https://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/main.htm

Your specific question - How do I create a folder shortcut to my existing SAS files?

https://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/shared_folder_access_existing.htm